# Help in a demonstration of a theorem in Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book (theorem 13 section 1.6)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand the final line of this demonstration of the theorem 13 (page 23) in [Hoffman and Kunze's linear algebra book](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-87D9cxiLfibzN1UTRkWTdHVFk/edit):

[image]

Using the previous theorem (theorem 12), I think we're done when the author proves that $R=I$. I didn't understand why the fact the system $AX=P^{-1}E$ has a solution has to do with $A$ being invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show that $R=I$. To show this, it suffices to show that the last row of $R$ is not identically $0$. As is mentioned in the part I guess you understand, to show that $R$ is not identically $0$, it suffices to show that $RX=E$ can be solved for $X$. Since $R=PA$, where $P$ is invertible, it follows that

$$
RX=E\iff (PA)X=E\iff P^{-1}(PA)X=P^{-1}E\iff AX=P^{-1}E.
$$

Now, by (iii), $AX=P^{-1}E$ has a solution in $X$, and, by the above, this same $X$ solves $RX=E$. This is precisely what was needed to show that $R=I$. Since $R=I$, it follows, by theorem 12, that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Happy to help :-)